# TV not see MiniDLNA server

Tags: networking

I have a Samsung TV with AllShare connected by Ethernet to a TP-LINK (
WR841N) WiFi router. AP Isolation is off. I also have a Linux laptop with MiniDLNA server on it. Ethernet from microtik router. All software (TV, Laptop, Router) is up to date.

When my laptop is connected to the router by Ethernet, the TV can see the server, but not when it is on WiFi.

I want to use media server while the laptop is on WiFi.

**Network extra information**:

*TV IP - 192.168.4.16*

*Router IP - 192.168.4.1*

*Wifi Devices (Laptop etc.) - 192.168.0.xxx*

[image: Map]

**Update**: I can ping my TV while on wifi. Maybe it's something in minidlna.conf ?

Comment: This kind of thing is almost always caused by the router not properly allowing communications between wired and wireless networks. You need to check the router settings or replace the router.

Comment: Try to (1) Temporarily disable the firewall on the router, (2) Update TV firmware to latest version (perhaps by menu on the remote > Support > Software Update), (3) Update router firmware. Question: Are you using for AllShare a dongle on the TV?

Comment: No, I don't use dongle, AllShare is default feature @harrymc

Comment: The key thing I notice is that wi-fi is using 192.168.0.x and the router and TV are 192.168.4.x. You likely have a routing problem caused by the inability to route traffic between these two networks. It looks like the MicroTik maybe set for DHCP on the 192.168.4.x network and then you segregate the wireless network using NAT again via the TP-LINK device. Is there any reason that the TP-LINK needs to be using DHCP/NAT and cannot just act as an AP?

Comment: Can I make this with DHCP? @MaQleod

Comment: You should disable DHCP/routing on the TP-LINK. There usually is an option to set it as AP only (basically turns it into a layer 2 switch), the process is slightly different from brand to brand. What model is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by checking the TP-Link configuration for a setting called wifi isolation or something to that effect. That prevents all wifi devices from seeing other devices and vice versa.

Depending on your model it should be somewhere in this menu:
Wireless -> Wireless Advanced -> Enable AP Isolation

Edit: Based on your new information it appears that the wifi is being assigned to a different network/subnet. You'll need to check the wifi settings to make sure that both the wifi and wired connection are on the same network. What that means is that all your devices are on the 192.168.4.XXX range.

Comment: It's off on my TP-Link, should I on it?

Comment: @StepanVanzuriak No :) Off is good in this particular case.